# How can you selectively export PATCH, PUT and POST for a @RestRepositoryResource?

Tags: spring-data-rest

I know that it is possible to use annotations to prevent the export of certain HTTP methods for a given repository, e.g:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AccountRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Account, Long> {

    @Override
    @RestResource(exported = false)
    Account save(Account entity);
}
```

If I understood the documentation correctly `save` is mapped to POST, PUT and PATCH. Is it possible to selectively prevent the export of these individually? For instance, in this case I want to allow PUT but prevent POST.

Comment: So the first point: just run the code and let us know if it's correct and save method really not exported. Regarding selective prevention of particular request types - just override the method and annotate it with allowed request types

Comment: I know that code works, it doesn't export it and POST, PUT and PATCH are not allowed. That's my question though - how do you do this selectively? I am not sure which annotations to use to disallow only certain methods.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a workaround which makes you to override automatically generated CRUD methods (by Spring Data REST) with your own controllers:

```
    public class CrudController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
        public String save(Model uiModel) {
            // code here
        }
    }
```